# Path Variable Not Working

Tags: java, windows, path, javac

I tried everything, but I still can't get my Path working:
[image: javac.exe is not a recognized command]

This is my PATH:
[image: Environment Variables]

This is my environment variables:
[image: Not Working]

My java bin folder contains java.exe

@David Wallace

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Andy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup>echo
 %PATH%
c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:
\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Window
sPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program
 Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Manage
ment Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Com
ponents\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\D
AL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared

C:\Users\Andy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup>

Comment: Did you restart your console after updating path variables?

Comment: Did  you edit your system variables before or after you opened that command window?

Comment: Yes, but I removed it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please try `echo %PATH%` in that same command window, just to see what you get?

Comment: Also, my Java is installed in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\ ` - that is, there's no `_45`.  Can you please double check that yours isn't the same?

Comment: Thats because I got update 45.

Comment: It's not showing up on the echo?

Comment: Really?  You're typing `echo %PATH%` and getting nothing at all?

Comment: No I put it on the post. It's too long to fit in a comment. I mean the java folder is not showing up.

Comment: OK, I'm still nervous about that `%` sign.  Can you click `Edit...` again for the `Path` system variable and copy-paste what shows up in the field into the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Instead of using a GUI to set the path, I used:

```
Path = %PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely have to use a space, and not a percent sign, in the path to the jdk (no quotes required).

But I actually recommend to use an IDE (e.g. Eclipse) which will do the compiling for you (and help you code much faster).

Comment: I use an IDE but I'm using this for another one of my programs. Thank you for your answer but I tried it already. I by mistake left in the percent.

Comment: You might have to edit the system variable 'Path' instead of creating a new user variable, or alternatively run the console from the jdk/bin directory.

Comment: No, I have it in the system Path variable too. You just can't see it in that picture. It's in the other picture.